# How can I adapt my level loader so it works on all android phones?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mobile

I'm making a game (just using eclipse and the android sdk) and I have a level building feature based on a text file input.

So, for example, "levelone.txt" might contain "[2,5],[14,7],[10,9]". When this file is loaded, 3 platforms would be created and sent to those positions.

This works fine on my test phone (240x320), but trying it on my friends phone with a much larger screen (720x1280), the coordinates are all wrong and only occupy a small space in the corner. How can I adapt what I have so far so it works on all android devices, scaling the coordinates accordingly depending on screen size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The math behind scaling your level loader is actually fairly simple.
First you should start by choosing your default scale. Meaning take your 240x320 screen resolution along with the coordinates and dimensions of your platforms

Now to scale it we should know the screen resolution of the device your game is running on. The following will grab the screen resolution for you:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

If you are targeting pre API 13 then you can't use display.getSize, instead you should use:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Now that we have the new resolution we can find the difference in scale between you default (240x320) resolution and the one on the new device:

```
float xScale = (float)width / 240.0f;
float yScale = (float)height / 320.0f;
```

**It is important to force these values to be a float or a double because it you leave them as an integer then it won't scale properly because the decimal values will be omitted and a you will have a rounded whole number. Which isn't accurate and won't allow for proper scaling.**

Once you have the scale you can start to resize and move your objects accordingly.

For example if your first platform's position was

```
int x = 200;
int y = 120;
```

then you would simply take those values and multiply them by the scale so:

```
int x = (int)(200 * xScale);
int y = (int)(120 * yScale);
```

You would also need to do this for the dimensions of the platform:

```
int width = (int)(30 * xScale);
int height = (int)(15 * yScale);
```

Replacing 30 and 15 with the width and height of the platform

**Important:**
When scaling your coordinates in this manner then you would need to scale all of them. This means if you are using coordinates for detecting boundaries and collisions those would also have to be scaled accordingly to match.

Here is another post on how to get an android device's resolution.

[Getting screen resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions)

Hope this helps and good luck.

Comment: An amazingly detailed answer. Thank you very much :)

Comment: No problem, just trying to help out.